# Finding a matrix of a linear map with respect to Bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Let $f:U \rightarrow V$ be a linear map where $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces.
Let $U$ be the vector space of polynomials degree $3$ in variable $t$. $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map defined by $f(u)=u'(1)$.
Find the matrix of $f$ with respect to bases $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$ and $\{1\}$.

Comment: I don't know if you have to do f(1) and then f(t) etc for elements of the basis?

Comment: Yes, and then these are the coefficients of your matrix (and this works for any map between two finite-dimensional vector spaces). Check out the answer below.

Comment: Thankyou that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

The matrix will have the shape $$\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
Where $a_i=f(t^i)$.

For example $a_0=f(1)=(t\mapsto 1)'(1)=(t \mapsto 0)(1)=0$ and $a_1=f(t)=(t\mapsto t)'(1)=(t \mapsto 1)(1)=1$ and $a_2=f(t^2)=(t\mapsto t^2)'(1)=(t \mapsto 2t)(1)=2$.

So the matrix is : $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

I will let you calculate $a_3$ in order to complete the matrix.

Comment: How generous of you.